# Удаленный доступ к сайту через телефон используя цифровой код или QR-код

Tags: javascript, html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста, ссылками на нужные ресурсы для решения моего вопроса: есть обычная html страница с теннисным счетом и разными кнопками (c исп. javascript) изменяющими этот счет и я хочу, чтобы эта же страница с кнопками открывалась на телефоне для изменения счета (либо через генерацию кода или с исп. QR-кода - не так важно). Помогите, пожалуйста, советом, что нужно изучить/почитать, пока даже не могу нагуглить =(
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/

Comment: доступ ограничивать, наверное, лучше не на клиенте, а на серверной части